# Java Projects that have .exe files don't run when there are JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, exe

Whenever putting JPanel into a Java project, and then transforming the project to an executable file (.exe), the executable file does not run. In other words, even clicking twice, the executable file with JPanel does nothing.

And if you remove JPanel, the executable file runs normally.
Please have you guys tested this yet?
How can I make projects that have JPanel run normally with .exe files?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU3ia.png)

Running on Launch4j:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yjC8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lll2.png)

Comment: I've done something similar with multiple different products (to generate the exe) without issue - you issue is localised to either your code or the way you are building the exe

Comment: Please, How are you generating the executable file?
I'm generating through Launch4j, writting the output file, the jar and the min JRE version

Comment: There should be an Error message.  Run your exe in a cmd.exe window.

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, even running into cmd.exe window, nothing happens, and there is no message error.

Comment: Have you read through http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.